# UIPageViewController page control not showing when used as a child controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

My controller hierarchy is as follows:

Tab View Controller (Parent) -> Main View Controller (Child)

Main View Controller (Parent) -> Page View Controller (Child)

Page View Controller (Parent) -> Secondary View Controller (Child)

When I navigate to the page view controller without setting it as a child view controller (but still within the tab view controller), the page control is visible at the bottom of the screen when I hide the tab bar.

When I use a container view in the Main View Controller to show the page view controller, the page control disappears (even with the tab bar hidden).

Why does this happen? Can I fix it/work around it?

Comment: Show how you are setting the page view controller as a child. Also, are you sure the page control isn't there? It is white on white by default, so it can seem to be invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "view debugger" and see if the "Page Control" is there:

[image]

If it is, you can use this view debugger to figure out why it's not visible (it may be white-on-white; it may be obscured by something else in front of it; it may be off-screen).

If it is not there, then add breakpoints in your [`presentationCountForPageViewController:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdatasource/1614095-presentationcountforpageviewcont?changes=latest_minor&language=objc) (aka `presentationCount(for:)`) and your [`presentationIndexForPageViewController:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdatasource/1614116-presentationindexforpageviewcont?changes=latest_minor&language=objc) (aka `presentationIndex(for:)`) and make sure they're getting called like you think they should. Also make sure controller’s transition style is [`UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollertransitionstyle/uipageviewcontrollertransitionstylescroll?changes=latest_minor&language=objc) as outlined in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdatasource?changes=latest_minor&language=objc).